# GRUB для Ubuntu и Windows на 2 разных дисках на 1 ноуте

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, grub

Купил ноут. В нем SSD с предустановленой виндой. Поставил дополнительно еще один ссд, на него поставил убунту.

В биосе меняю приоритет загрузки на убунту - появляется граб, но могу выбрать только Ubuntu.

Меняю приоритет на винду, загружается только винда, без возможности выбора ОС.
Как мне дать понять грабу, что у мня уже 2 ОС стоит на ноуте?

Comment: Поставь os-prober

Comment: `update-grub` пробовал? Он должен находить все ОС на всех девайсах и обновлять `grub.cfg`.

Comment: @donRumata нет, это команда или утилита?

Comment: это команда, ну спасибо, попробую сейчас

Comment: @donRumata не сработало(((

Comment: А выхлоп апдейт-граба можно посмотреть?